# Combining text values in a pandas dataframe column based on same value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data where I may have different people associated with the same entry.

I need to combine the two entries together and note that two people are on it.

For example, the data may look like:

```
Name Share_ID value1 value2 value3 etc.
Joe  0001     1      2      4
Ann  0002     2      5      2
Mel  0001     1      2      4
```

The output would need to be:

```
Name      Share_ID value1 value2 value3 etc.
Joe, Mel  0001     1      2      4
Ann       0002     2      5      2
```

I tried to use groupby

```py
df1.groupby(['Share_ID'])['Name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

But my result from that was just:

```
Share_ID Name
0001     Joe, Mel
0002     Ann
```

The Name column combined correctly, but I lost the other columns. Note that I do not want the other columns to have anything applied to them--Joe and Ann's records are identical.

I think my approach is off, but I'm not sure what function to use.

Comment: did you check with groupby ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting where you left off you could just join your resulting data set back to the initial DataFrame:

```
# Find the merged name data set and rename the 'Name' column
names = df1.groupby(['Share_ID'])['Name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index().rename(columns={'Name':'Merged Name'})
# Join it to the original dataset
df1 = df1.merge(names, on='Share_ID')
# Drop the 'Name' column then drop duplicates.
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['Name']).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Wonderful. I appreciate that it's broken down into multiple lines and that the column renames happen in order to prevent having a bunch of Name_x and Name_y columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the outcome you got, merge it with the original dataframe, and drop duplicates:

```
pd.merge(df1.groupby(['Share_ID'])['Name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index(), df1, on='Share_ID').drop_duplicates(subset='Share_ID')
```

Comment: This is a great solution; I marked the other as accepted simply because it's a little bit more readable for me as a new user (so when I review my code later, I'll be more likely to remember what was done).

Comment: @RoccoMaxamas Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason for not using `values` fields in group by?

```
df1.groupby(['Share_ID','value1', 'value2', 'value3'])['Name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

This will give the required output.